# Picasa API returns "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."

Tags: c#, gdata-api, picasa

My Code:

```
foreach (PicasaEntry entryAlbuns in feedAlbuns.Entries)
{                
   AlbumAccessor ac = new AlbumAccessor(entryAlbuns);
   PhotoQuery photos = new PhotoQuery(PicasaQuery.CreatePicasaUri("admin@localhost", ac.AlbumTitle));
   PicasaFeed feedPhotos = service.Query(photos);
}
```

When debugger step in line PicasaFeed feedPhotos = service.Query(photos); get an error

> The remote server returned an error:
> (404) Not Found.

Check parameters accepted:

[image]

PS: Because of security reasons I replaced my email account to admin@localhost.

Comment: Perhaps the API is down?

Comment: I don't know if is down, but if remove ac.AlbumTitle from parameter, api get me all images in all albuns. But not work with albumtitle filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem.

For Google API 1.2.2.0
Use the AlbumAccessor.Name instead of AlbumAccessor.AlbumTitle.
Google should make this more obvious in the documentation.

For Google APL 1.4.0.2 
Use the AlbumAccessor.Id instead of AlbumAccessor.AlbumTitle.
Google should make this more obvious in the documentation.

Sample Code:

```
AlbumAccessor ac = new AlbumAccessor(AlbumEntry);
PhotoQuery query = new PhotoQuery();
query.Uri = new Uri(PicasaQuery.CreatePicasaUri(_login,AlbumAccessor.Id));                                

photoFeed = picasaService.Query(query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check .. the title must have no space, if you use ac.name you will get the good name of album .... wish that help some people